# Android: RunTimeException with Robolectric Shadow Package Parser

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

I'm running a unit tests using RobolectricTestRunner but am seeing a NPE caused by a Shadow Package Parser Exception

I have configured the test class as such:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(application = RobolectricTestApp.class)
public class YourRoomsActivityTest {
    @Test
    public void test_dummy() {
        // Required until real tests are added back
    }
...
}
```

The exception:
java.lang.RuntimeException at ShadowPackageParser.java:69
Caused by: android.content.pm.PackageParser$PackageParserException at PackageParser.java:1353
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at CppAssetManager2.java:689

Comment: There are two open issues in the Robolectric repo that seem at least somewhat related to this problem. [#4278](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/4278) and [#5597](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/5597).